# .NET Core REST API - run code after delay in another thread

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project in **c# .Net Core 3.1**.

Where I have to run code after a delay.

**Quick description:**

I create auction with end dateTime.

I have to run a function (connect DB, close auction item, etc...) when this auction ends.

I can create more of these action items, so I have to run this function when the earliest item ends.

After each item ends I have to reset this time (delay) to the next auction item dateTime.


All of this I want in a separate thread for non-blocking main thread.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Sounds good to me. What specifically is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I dont know how can I run and change delay of run the function

Comment: I think [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) might be a good solution in this case

Comment: I looked on Hangfire, but I dont like an SchedulePollingInterval setting. I need set this setting to 1 second and Its not good for performance I think.

Comment: in hangfire your can start the backgroud job immediatelly after submitting. 

var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Fire-and-forget!"))

https://www.hangfire.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with running this as part of your application, take a look at [background tasks in .NETCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) for running these tasks.

If you require them to run independently, for instance you may want to take your site down but still have the auctions end correctly, you could use something like [Azure WebJobs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

There's a nice article with a comparison here; https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/13/hosted-services-in-asp-net-core/

Given the frequency of the task, I suggest you don't load data on each loop of the process. Take a slightly different approach;

- Load any auctions in the next X (10?) minutes, ordered by date ending
- Once auction ending == now, perform the closing actions you require
- Once per minute, load in new data if any

Comment: I want run this as a part of aplication. This auction ends are set in directly time so I have to check every second.